# Wordpress - using advanced custom field plugin for a template file

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm using ACF for a Wordpress site for the first time. I have a template file that I use across a number of pages - `topimage-agency.php` - and I need to make a paragraph within it dynamic. 
I've created the custom field using wysiwyg editor and selected the main Agency Page -

[image: ACF Selector]

Obviously I haven't set the template up with its own page so I've had to select one. The code is dynamic on the agency page and all works fine however it doesn't show/work any differently on any of the other pages. Is there a way I can make elements of a template dynamic using ACF or any other way?

Answer (score 0):

You need to select Page Template  instead of page. Then You Select Page Template name instead of page name(AGENCY). 
If you do like this, your custom field will appear all the pages where you specify that template.

Hope this helps to you!!!

Comment: No, that hasn't worked. I don't have the template set up on pages because it is not a page, it is a template so where would I edit the content?

Comment: All I need to know is, where do you set up global templates for editing content purposes? Other than via appearances>editor .

Comment: Create a page and setup that template.. No other way to set up global templates.. I hope so..